# How to assign macro to table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to assign a macro to a table so it will be enough to change only in one place. That is, instead of writing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Data].[dbo].[Today_is_20220720]
```

I want to write something like:

```
DECLARE @Mytable = [Data].[dbo].[Today_is_20220720]

SELECT * 
FROM @Mytable
```

I do not want to have to specify all the columns in `[Data].[dbo].[Today_is_20220720]` for it to work.

Comment: Questionable design aside, SQL Server does not support macro substitution.  This would require Dynamic SQL which can be a slippery slope.  That said, you could take a peek at CREATE SYNONYM   https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-synonym/

Comment: This worked:
`CREATE SYNONYM Mytable FOR [Data].[dbo].[Today_is_20220720];

SELECT * FROM Mytable`

Comment: Happy it helped  Just remember it has to be managed or you may get some unexpected results.

Comment: Now what happens if multiple queries are querying different tables simultaneously using `Mytable`.... It's a ridiculous design, just use the actual names and specify the columns. Perhaps you should be using an ORM or something?

Comment: Isn't it just a view you want?